# Get networkx subgraph containing all nodes in between

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-theory

I have a networkx DiGraph and I want to extract a subgraph from it by passing in a list of nodes. The subgraph however can contain all nodes that might be in between the nodes that I have passed. I checked `nx.subgraph()` but it does not work like I intend to. As for a small example:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
edges = [(7, 4), (3, 8), (3, 2), (3, 0), (3, 1), (7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 8)]
G.add_edges_from(edges)
H = get_subgraph(G, [0,6,7,8])
```

How can I write the function `get_subgraph()` so that H has the edges `[(3, 8), (3, 0), (7, 6), (7, 8)]`? 
The subgraph I need is such that it contains all the nodes that are in the ougoing and incoming paths between the nodes that I pass in the `get_subgraph()`function. 
[image: The subgraph I want from the graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do this could be to find the longest path length between the specified set of nodes, and then find the corresponding induced subgraph containing all nodes in the path. However, being a directed graph, there will be no direct path between say nodes `3` and `7`. So we need to find the paths in an undirected copy of the graph. Let's set up the problem:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
edges = [(7, 4), (3, 8), (3, 2), (3, 0), (3, 1), (7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 8)]
G.add_edges_from(edges)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, scale=20, k=3/np.sqrt(G.order()))
nx.draw(G, pos, node_color='lightblue', 
        with_labels=True, 
        node_size=1500,
        arrowsize=20)
```

[image]

Now we ca obtain and undirected copy of the graph with [`nx.to_undirected`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.to_undirected.html) and find all [`nx.shortest_path_length`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path_length.html) for the specified nodes:

```
from itertools import combinations

H = nx.to_undirected(G)

nodelist = [0,6,7,8]
paths = {}
for nodes in combinations(nodelist, r=2):
    paths[nodes] = nx.shortest_path_length(H, *nodes)

print(paths)
# {(0, 6): 4, (0, 7): 3, (0, 8): 2, (6, 7): 1, (6, 8): 2, (7, 8): 1}
```

We can find the longest path in the undirected graph with:

```
max_path = max(paths.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
longest_induced_path = nx.shortest_path(H, *max_path)
```

And the corresponding induced subgraph can be obtained with [`Graph.subgraph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html):

```
sG = nx.subgraph(G, longest_induced_path)

pos = nx.spring_layout(sG, scale=20, k=3/np.sqrt(G.order()))
nx.draw(sG, pos, node_color='lightblue', 
        with_labels=True, 
        node_size=1500,
        arrowsize=20)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i understand this from question:
you need all nodes in a path but provide some nodes of that path and algorithm should give all nodes of that path and then you can pass that nodes to a graph and make a new graph.
it should be what you want:
1. you must iterate over all pairs of nodes with this method:

```
from itertools import combinations
b= combinations('ABCD', 2)
print(list(b))  --> [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')]
```

2. you must get all pathes with this:
   https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/simple_paths.html
3. you must select path with maximum nodes and that is your solution.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your input. This is similar to yatu's answer